# Facebook Graph API Take Photograph with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i've tried to take the user's profile photo with using graph api, i take first name, email,fb id exc true, but i fail on taking the user's profile pictures, tried everything and read everything but failed.

After connecting with facebook, it shows a big question mark in the photo areas in my websites' profile picture area for the profiles..

Also there is no problem about temp_fb_id parametre, its inserting that true too

Here is my codes :

```
// above is the part with sessions getting user id, user email exc.
// $temp_fb_id is the variable that i use for taking the info for user name exc and its working but with photo part, not working , 
 //  img src is showing https://graph.facebook.com//picture?type=square,with a output, big question mark

 $first_name = $user->first_name;
 $last_name = $user->last_name;

 $photo = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$temp_fb_id}/picture?type=square";
 $photothumb = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$temp_fb_id}/picture?type=normal";
 $photolarge = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$temp_fb_id}/picture?type=large";


try {
$fb_insert = "INSERT INTO `members`(`first_name`, `photo_small`, `photo_thumb`, `photo`, `last_name`, `fb_id`) VALUE(:first_name, :photo, :photothumb, :photolarge, :last_name, :temp_fb_id)";
 $fb_insert_do = $db->prepare($fb_insert);
 $fb_insert_do->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $fb_insert_do->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $fb_insert_do->bindParam(':photo', $photo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $fb_insert_do->bindParam(':photothumb', $photothumb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $fb_insert_do->bindParam(':photolarge', $photolarge, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $fb_insert_do->execute();
 }

 catch(PDOException $e) {
            /* catch and log errors over here. */
        }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the user IDs you are passing are incorrect for some reason. You should compare the results of `$user->id` to what you are storing in `$tmp_fb_id` to make sure the values are equal. You should be able to paste one of these urls into the `src` of an `img` tag and have it render the photo. You could also replace the id with `$user->username` to see if it is any better.

A question: Why are you storing these URLs in your database instead of generating them at runtime from the stored Id? You'll have to update all your db records if Facebook decides to change the url scheme to get profile photos in the future, instead of just a few lines of code.

Comment: oh sorry fixed it, erased my database record, because was trying to do with always same facebook id, and was erasing facebook app everytime, thank you very much. also want to ask an another quetion, shadowbox doesn't work with https://graph.facebook.com/*******/picture?type=large this, do you know why can this happen, thanks again

Comment: you're right with your question also, i'll work on that too, thank you again.

Comment: The default for Facebook is to return a 302 redirect to the photo. Not sure how shadowbox works. Try adding `&redirect=false` to the end of your URL. Facebook returns a string instead.

Comment: made the links like `https://graph.facebook.com/{$temp_fb_id}/picture?type=large&redirect=false` but now it doesn't recognize the photos, can't get the string from facebook. shadowbox works like `<a href="biggerphotourl" rel="shadowbox">smallphotohere</a>` when you click the small photo it opens the bigger photo in javascript like popup window.

Comment: Ask another question with your php code that generates this. I'll watch for it. SO doesn't want you to ask new questions in the comments. If you can include a public url to inspect, that would be great too.